# Error in dapp developed using 'Truffle' framework - Issue in fetching the result from Oraclize-Query

Tags: contract-design, truffle, testrpc, oracles

I am developing a dapp using 'testrpc' and 'truffle'-3.1.1.I have also used ethereum-bridge for Oraclize.I have written a smart contract function which calls a url using 'OraclizeQuery'.

The following is the contract code :-

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

 import "./usingOraclize.sol";
 contract WeatherApiCall is usingOraclize {
       string public weathercondition;
       event LOG_OraclizeCallback(
              bytes32 queryId,
              string result
       );
       function WeatherApiCall() {
            OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x44bc501f0d92a9583877636828f52abc9da5d585);//OAR address
      }
      function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
              if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
              weathercondition=result;
              LOG_OraclizeCallback(myid,result);
      }
      function update(string to,string datetime) payable returns(bool sufficient) {

              oraclize_query("URL", strConcat("json(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='", to ,"'&mode=json&APPID=d2e8279188c8649c17540f798c9cc972).list[?(@.dt_txt='", datetime, "')].weather[0].main"));
              return true;
  }
}
```

The following is the index.html file :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Sample Truffle App</title>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Airline</h1>
        <h2>Example Truffle Dapp</h2>
        <br>
       <h1>Form</h1>
               <br><label for="from">From:</label><input type="text" id="from" placeholder="--Residing Place--"></input>
               <br><label for="to">To:</label><input type="text" id="to" placeholder="--Travelling Place--"></input>
               <br><label for="persons">No. of Persons:</label><input type="text" id="persons" placeholder="--No. of Persons--"></input>
               <br><label for="date">Travel Date:</label><input type="text" id="date" placeholder="--Date of travel yyyy-MM-dd--"></input>
               <br><label for="time">Destination Time:</label><input type="text" id="time" placeholder="--HH:mm:ss--"></input>
               <br><br><button id="send" onclick="App.sendRequest()">Generate Quote</button> 
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is the app.js file.

```
  // Import the page's CSS. Webpack will know what to do with it.
  import "../stylesheets/app.css";

 // Import libraries we need.
 import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
 import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'

 // Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
 import weatherapicall_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/WeatherApiCall.json'

// WeatherApiCall is our usable abstraction, which we'll use through the code below.
var WeatherApiCall = contract(weatherapicall_artifacts);

 // The following code is simple to show off interacting with your contracts.
// As your needs grow you will likely need to change its form and structure.
// For application bootstrapping, check out window.addEventListener below.
var accounts;
var account;


  window.App = {
    start: function() {
    var self = this;

    // Bootstrap the WeatherApiCall abstraction for Use.
    WeatherApiCall.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

   // Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
   web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
          if (err != null) {
             alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
             return;
          }

         if (accs.length == 0) {
               alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
               return;
         }

          accounts = accs;
          account = accounts[0];
     });
  },

  sendRequest: function() {
         var queryRecheck = function(contract){

         var bn = web3.eth.blockNumber; // returns the current block number
         var logger = contract.LOG_OraclizeCallback(null, { fromBlock: bn });

        console.log('Waiting on Oraclize queries...');
        console.log(bn);
        console.log(logger);

                 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        var ctr = setInterval(function () {
                        logger.get(function (error, events) {
                        if (error)
                             reject(error);

                        try {
                              if (typeof events !== 'undefined') {
                                  events.forEach(function (evt) {
                                      if (evt.args.block.toNumber() > bn) {
                                       clearInterval(ctr);
                                       resolve();
                                    }
                              });
                      }
                      } catch (e) {
                         console.log('Error encountered during query wait: ' + e);
                         reject(e);
                     }
                 });
                 }, 50000);
                });
              }
              var self = this;
              var fromdata = document.getElementById("from").value;
              var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
              var persons = parseInt(document.getElementById("persons").value);
              var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
              var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
             //verifying at javascript console
              console.log(fromdata);
              console.log(to);
              console.log(persons);
              console.log(date);
              console.log(time);
              var timeperiod;
              if ((time >= '00:00:00') && (time < '03:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '00:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '03:00:00') && (time < '06:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '03:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '06:00:00') && (time < '09:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '06:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '09:00:00') && (time < '12:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '09:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '12:00:00') && (time < '15:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '12:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '15:00:00') && (time < '18:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '15:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '18:00:00') && (time < '21:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '18:00:00';
              } else if ((time >= '21:00:00') && (time < '24:00:00')) {
                        timeperiod = '21:00:00';
              }
              var datetime = date + ' ' + timeperiod;
              console.log(datetime);

               WeatherApiCall.deployed().then(function(instance) {

                          console.log("Initializing");
                          instance.update(to,datetime, {from: account, gas: 3000000, value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')})
                               .then(function(v){
                                       console.log(v);
                                       console.log("Function Executed");
                                       return queryRecheck(instance);
                                 }).then(function(events) {
                                       console.log(events);
                                 });
                       }).then(function() {
                                              console.log("Testing");
                       }).catch(function(e) {
                                               console.log(e);
                       });
  }
};

 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
      // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
      window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
               console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
               // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
              window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
               }
              App.start();
 });
```

The following is the output generated at javascript console :-

```
 "No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask"    app.js:25575:5
 india                     app.js:25520:4
 chennai                   app.js:25521:4
 2                         app.js:25522:4
 2017-03-02                app.js:25523:4
 12:00                     app.js:25524:4
 2017-03-02 09:00:00       app.js:25544:4
 Initializing              app.js:25549:27
 Testing                   app.js:25561:50
  Object { tx: "0xcaf76e6444507c3fb48007c3e7307a8dc…", receipt: Object, logs: Array[0] }               app.js:25552:41
  Function Executed        app.js:25553:41
  Waiting on Oraclize queries... app.js:25486:8
  15                       app.js:25487:8
  Object { requestManager: Object, options: Object, implementation: Object, filterId: null, callbacks: Array[0], getLogsCallbacks: Array[0], pollFilters: Array[0], formatter: bound () }        app.js:25488:8
  Error encountered during query wait: TypeError: evt.args.block is undefined                       app.js:25506:24
  Error encountered during query wait: TypeError: evt.args.block is undefined                       app.js:25506:24
  Error encountered during query wait: TypeError: evt.args.block is undefined                       app.js:25506:24
```

I have tried to print the result of Oraclize-Query in javascript console...But it return's the error...How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your event is working as intended and not empty (add some console.log on the `events` before processing it).
As you can see `block` is missing in the `evt` object, probably because your `LOG_OraclizeCallback` event ( https://github.com/Kottackal-ET-Practice/Flight-Dapp/blob/d5f6e5a661517e00ff37f48052b5e3a1afa8558d/contracts/WeatherApiCall.sol#L8-L13 ) doesn't have `block` in it, if you are trying to get the block number from the log you can access that via the `blockNumber` parameter in the `evt` object (`evt.blockNumber`).